# After uninstalling Boot Camp disk space did not restore

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

It's been a pain for me to install windows 10 on my Mac. I failed and decided to use a different iso. I uninstalled windows via bootcamp - it said it restored the memory succesfully. However the 150GB I allocated to my Windows did not come back. 
[image]

Any help? Attaching my `diskutil list`

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         848.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s3
   4:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s4
   5:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s5
   6:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk0s6

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +848.6 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh SSD - Data    685.3 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 84.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.1 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh SSD           11.0 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS WinInstall              500.1 GB   disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US... +5.4 GB     disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Boot Camp              +2.8 GB     disk4
```

P.S. `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1 0g` did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first remove all those unneeded EFI partitions.

```
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s6
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s5
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s4
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```